# Finding the main phases of the Moon in a particular month

Tags: list-manipulation

My aim is to build a function that has parameters month and year and returns four lists, namely with the dates of the new moon, first quarter, full moon, last quarter.

This is more possible after Mathematica 10 because of the `MoonPhase` function. It works like this:

```
MoonPhase[DateObject[{2017, 1, 5, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> +2], "Name"]
```

or without the `"Name"`. It returns either `Entity["MoonPhase", something]` or just a lunation degree [0, 1]. Here is an example for the whole January of 2017:

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, the algorithm associating a name to the lunation degree doesn't succeed in finding the full moon on 12th of January. This is probably because the algorithm needs the date and hour (in this case 12/01/2017,00:00) to be with a lunation degree at least some number close to 1, which it isn't. When I change the time to be `DateObject[{2017,1,i,12,0}]`, it finds the full moon.

So do you have any suggestion how to fix this in a smart way?